# Pythonic use of iterations and conditionals

Tags: python, iteration, conditional-statements

This is a slightly general question - I'm looking for the most pythonic and / or efficient approach:

I have a large dataset and a number of tasks that sometimes need to be performed by iterating through the rows, and sometimes don't, depending on some conditions.

```
for step in np.arange (0, number_of_steps):
    if condition1:
        do_calculation1(step)
    if condition2:
        do_calculation2(step)
```

So both `if` statements are repeated on every iteration. The conditions are true or false for the whole dataset, so to save time, I will not do the iteration if it's not needed:

```
if condition1 or condition2:
    for step in np.arange (0, number_of_steps):
            if condition1:
                do_calculation1(step)
            if condition2:
                do_calculation2(step)
```

but I am still repeating `if` statements sometimes unnecessarily.
The alternative would be to separate the conditional statements and do two iterations through the dataset:

```
if condition1 :
    for step in np.arange (0, number_of_steps):
        do_calculation1(step)
if condition2:
    for step in np.arange (0, number_of_steps):
        do_calculation2(step)
```

The disadvantage of this is that if both conditions are true, I iterate twice, which is slow (and clumsy). The relative speed of the 2 approaches will depend on how often each of the conditions is true, but I will be using a wide variety of data, so I don't know which will be quicker.

So my question is which would be the most pythonic and most efficient approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
calculations = [
    f for c,f in [
        (condition1, do_calculation1),
        (condition2, do_calculation2),
    ] if c
]
if calculations:
    for step in np.arange (0, number_of_steps):
        for calc in calculations:
            calc(step)
```

Comment: Love this - pythonic and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply combine both of your methodologies:

```
if not condition1 and not condition2:
    pass
elif not condition1 and condition2
    for step in np.arange (0, number_of_steps):
        do_calculation1(step)
elif condition1 and not condition2:
    for step in np.arange (0, number_of_steps):
        do_calculation2(step)
else: # condition 1 and condition2:
    for step in np.arange (0, number_of_steps):
        do_calculation1(step)
        do_calculation2(step)
```

I guess this is more a question of efficiency rather than what would be more pythonic.

I guess this would be more pythonic:

```
def run_calcs(number_of_steps, *funcs):
    for step in range(number_of_steps):
        for func in funcs:
            func(step)

def gen_func_list(condition1=False, condition2=False):
    func_list = []
    if condition1:
        func_list.append(do_calculation1)
    if condition2:
        func_list.append(do_calculation2)
    return func_list

if __name__ == '__main__':

    number_of_steps = 10

    run_calcs(
        number_of_steps,
        *gen_func_list(
            condition1=<your condition here>,
            condition2=<your condition here>
        )
    )
```

I think this is also pretty readable and lends itself to multiprocessing:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def run_calcs(number_of_steps, *funcs):
    for step in range(number_of_steps):
        for func in funcs:
            func(step)

def gen_func_list(condition1=True, condition2=True):
    func_list = []
    if condition1:
        func_list.append(do_calculation1)
    if condition2:
        func_list.append(do_calculation2)
    return func_list

if __name__ == '__main__':

    number_of_steps = 10

    funcs = gen_func_list(
            condition1=<your condition here>,
            condition2=<your condition here>
    )

    proc_handles = []
    for f in funcs:
        proc_handles.append(
            Process(target=run_calcs,
                    args=[number_of_steps, f])
        )

    for p in proc_handles:
        p.start()

    for p in proc_handles:
        p.join()
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is more efficient. I guess I'm looking for efficiency *and* pythonicity (?).

Comment: @doctorer Thanks, now it's a bit more pythonic and even more performant.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first is the more pythonic approach. But if you really want to skip iteration if no condition is met you could add a break statement:

```
for ... :
    if not any(condition 1, condition2):
        break
    else:
        if condition1:
            ...
        if condition2:
            ...
```

This would allow you to avoid iteration on first step, or to check both conditions if any is met.

(sorry for the formatting, typing from phone.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the first approach is the best given your data set either has a condition (1 and/or 2) or not.

```
for step in np.arange (0, number_of_steps):
if condition1:
    do_calculation1(step)
if condition2:
    do_calculation2(step)
```

If both the conditions are mutually exclusive then you could replace the second if with an elif. This will save some computation.

```
for step in np.arange (0, number_of_steps):
if condition1:
    do_calculation1(step)
elif condition2:
    do_calculation2(step)
```